# How to rotate a particular fragment activity using tabhost in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation, fragment-tab-host

I have implemented **tabhost** with fragments in my project and in a particular tab I have implemented a fragment activity, the same activity I need it in both the orientation **landscape** and **portrait** but I can't do this.

When I rotate this activity with the below code, the rest of all tabs with fragments automatically changed into the landscape mode.

```
android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
```

Your additional efforts will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify screenorinetation to the parent activity not the individual activity.

For example Suppose you have 3 Fragments and those 3 fragmnets attached to a Parent activity called ParentA

now in your manifest under the activity field of ParentA specifiy screenorientation="unspecified".You don't need to specify individual activity screenorientation specified to the various fragment.

Comment: I got this point, but what my intention is to tell you that suppose I have three tabs named Home, Music & Video in which I already created a fragment activity in a Music tab.

Now what I am telling you that I need to specify the orientation for the new created fragment in Music tab, that thing I can't do this. And I already mention the orientaion to that particular tab container in Android.manifest file.

Comment: your implementation is not the ideal way.No matter how many fragments you are creating that should attached to a parent activity.when you tap on Music it should open MusicFragment attached to parent Activity.when you tap on Home or Video the same implementation goes

Comment: another thing you dont have to mention orientation change to the various fragments...override your onConfigchange method  in the ParentA activity...

Comment: after override...check which fragment is in stack top..make necessary changes after that...you can get current fragment status by FragmentManger

Answer (score 1):

Check the orientation and request to change it:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().screenOrientation != (Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE|Configuration.ORIENTATION_POTRAIT)) {
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(Configuration.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
} else {
}
```

---

> *Open for correction, as always!
>   Regards,
>   Edward Quixote.*